# Não consigo fechar uma tab(guia) com javascript

Tags: javascript, asp

Meu universo é o seguinte:

O atendente está com uma guia aberta, fazendo, óbvio, um atendimento. Ao encerrar esse atendimento, a URA já starta um segundo atendimento. Acontece que a URA abre outra guia. Ao encerrar esse atendimento, essa guia não é fechada e se a URA abrir outro, vai ficar aberto tantas guias quanto a URA abrir. Teria que vir manualmente fechando, sendo que pelo menos uma guia deve ficar aberta, devido ao login, ou seja a primeira guia. O que passa é que a URA é um agente externo, logo essa guia(page) aberta, não pode ser controlada pela guia que está aberta, pois não foi ela quem abriu. Gostaria de fazer um código(javascript) que fechasse a guia em questão.
Já tentei:

```
parent.self.close();
window.close();
self.close();
```

Enfim, foram várias tentativas e nenhuma deu certo.A guia não fecha.

Usamos `ASP` Clássico e `Javascript`.

```
    <script defer language="javascript">
                    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                        window.open('ace002c.asp?/cal/asp/cal0087b.asp$$$pt=Atendimento&pcf=ATB0082&num_associado=<%=num_associado%>&ind_origem_consulta=A&statusAtendimento=A&vinculacao=beneficiario&origem=CALLCENTER&tipo_atendimento_beneficiario=N', 'JANELA', 'top=0,left=0'); 
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(3);                       
                        sessionStorage.setItem("URL_ATENDIMENTO_URA", true); 
                         window.open("ace002c.asp?/cal/asp/cal0087b.asp$$$pt=Atendimento&pcf=ATB0082&num_associado=<%=num_associado%>&ind_origem_consulta=A&statusAtendimento=A&vinculacao=beneficiario&origem=CALLCENTER&tipo_atendimento_beneficiario=N", '_blank');                  
}

//open(location, '_self').close();
                    //alert(12);
                    //debugger;
                    window.onbeforeunload = null;
                    //console.log('teste1');
                    parent.self.close();
                    //alert(13);
                </script
```

>

E esse código abaixo, eu simulo a URA:

```
http://teste.dev.amil.com.br/ace/iniciaAtendimento.asp?protocolo=326338
```

> As páginas são abertas dentro de FRAMES(IFrame). Esse sistema é um
>   legado aqui na empresa.

Quando eu uso o `_self`, ele carrega as informações e fecha ele mesmo(`parent.self.close()`), porem não popa a tela do usuário. O que deve ser feito é que a tela de atendimento deve ser popada, independente qual tela esteja aberta pelo usuário, normalmente ela não fica aberta ao encerrar um atendimento. Fiz dessa forma com `_self`.

```
window.open("ace002c.asp?/cal/asp/cal0087b.asp$$$pt=Atendimento&pcf=ATB0082&num_associado=<%=num_associado%>&ind_origem_consulta=A&statusAtendimento=A&vinculacao=beneficiario&origem=CALLCENTER&tipo_atendimento_beneficiario=N", '_self');
```

Comment: Qual é o código para abrir novas guias? queres que feche de dentro da guia ou controlando de fora da guia?

Comment: Tente window.open(location, '_self').close(); Qual navegador/versão está usando ?

Comment: @MauroAlexandre, chrome

Comment: Não funcionou também. Faltou uma informação importante e vou editar o post.

Comment: No IE funciona. Por que? Bem, no IE é possível dar nome as janelas e dessa forma, creio eu que o IE use seus mecanismos internos para localizar essas janelas e dessa forma fechá-las, abrí-las e etc. O Chrome não possui esse conceito pelo que eu entendi.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é possível fechá-lo de maneira direta, mas uma opção é encontrar o iframe pelo seu ID/class na página que o contém e então removê-lo.

```
parent.document.getElementById("id_do_iframe").remove()
```

Comment: Emoon, não funcionou dessa forma também. Fiz uma rápida pesquisa e todos disseram que o que eu estou querendo, no chrome, não é possível.

Comment: No meu último edit, entendi que o chrome não abre a tela de atendimento, porque a URA simula uma segunda pessoa, ou seja, essa outra aba foi aberta não de dentro da guia aberta, mas por um outro elemento externo, no caso a URA, por isso a tela não popa.

Comment: Se tiver como alterar o script de chamada da tela de atendimento poderia usar o window.location.replace("http//xxx.com.br") e até mesmo dentro de um temporizador, exemplo: setTimeout(function () { window.location.replace("http//xxx.com.br"); }, 1000).